# Numerical solution for two diffusion equations connected by a jump

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I'm trying to solve the following PDE problem numerically:

$$
\partial_t u_1(r,t) = D_1\nabla^2u_1(r,t), \;r<R\\
\partial_t u_2(r,t) = D_2\nabla^2u_2(r,t), \;r>R\\
$$
connected by
$$
u_1(r=R^-, t) \;= \;\alpha\cdot u_2(r=R^+, t)\\
D_1\nabla u_1(r=R^-, t) \;= \;D_2\nabla u_2(r=R^+, t)
$$

I'm at a loss at how to connect the two domains and unfortunately seem to not get my search terms right to find a numerical scheme that would allow solving this system.

I'd be interested in:

(1) software (like Matlab's pdepe, etc..) that can solve such problems

(2) any advice on the numerics or being pointed to references that actually implement such a problem.

Thanks!

Comment: What is keeping you from applying finite differences? You just need transform the interface into two virtual layers of nodes, each connected to one of the sub-domains. You may also want to look for "Domain Decomposition Methods".

Comment: Great, thanks already! But I guess transforming the interface is my problem: I can't think of how to enforce the matching condition, while still using an algorithm that's faster than finite differences. Do you know of any examples, by any chance, that do something similar, but optimised for time? I guess my problem is that I've worked with finite differences, but that's most of what I know about numerics...

Comment: When I speak of transformation it is not in the mathematical sense... It is just introducing multiple degrees of freedom to the same physical node.

Comment: Ok, but this means you have to solve an algebraic equation at every time step, so you can get the correct boundary values where both domains are connected. Is this correct? If yes, are there any shortcuts I could take, to make this as fast as possible? To me it seems I literally have to solve the problem in both domains using finite differences and at each time step resolve the mismatch at the boundary.